# jQuery UI tabs: get current tab index

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, tabs

I want to get the index of the current tab using `jQuery UI` tabs: especially when the `show` or `select` events are fired i want to know the tab thay are referred is this possible?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

```
$('#tabs').tabs({
    select: function(event, ui) { // select event
        $(ui.tab); // the tab selected
        ui.index; // zero-based index
    },
    show: function(event, ui) { // show event
        $(ui.tab); // the tab shown
        ui.index; // zero-based index
    }
});
```

[**Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/Shef/k6TEZ/)

---

Or, if you don't want to bind the event listeners on the initialization you can bind them like this:

```
$('#tabs')
    .bind('tabsselect', function(event, ui) { // select event
        $(ui.tab); // the tab selected
        ui.index; // zero-based index
    })
    bind('tabsshow'. function(event, ui) { // show event
        $(ui.tab); // the tab shown
        ui.index; // zero-based index
    });
```

Comment: Hey Can you please suggest which is better among these two ?

Comment: @HardikMishra I would suggest the first one, because it won't break if the event names somehow end up changed in the future!

Comment: ui.index is undefined for "activate" which is the required event for newer versions of jQuery.  Do you know how to get the index on the activate event?

Answer (score 35):

You can use this to find

```
var $tabs = $('#tab').tabs();
var selected = $tabs.tabs('option', 'selected');
```

From JQuery 1.9 on

```
var $tabs = $('#tab').tabs();
var selected = $tabs.tabs('option', 'active');
```

Comment: +1 for showing how to find the selected tab outside of the show or select events. Not what the OP asked, but what I needed to know.

Answer (score 3):

I just implemented this in one of my projects:

```
var lastTab = 0; // global variable

$(function() {
    $('#tabs').tabs({ 
        select: function(event, ui) { 
            lastTab = ui.index; 
        } 
    });
});
```

And then anywhere else in your code you can simply reference `lastTab`.

Answer (score 1):

For jQuery 1.9 or newer...

```
$('#tabs').tabs({
    activate: function(event, ui) {
        ui.newTab.index(); // zero-based index
    }
});
```