# Selecting and loading a tab in jQuery 1.9.1 with jQuery ui 1.10.3

Tags: jquery, ajax

How do you select a given tab programatically using jQuery tabs

eg: when page loads, select tab 1(zero-based)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

gotten the answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/970838/selecting-loading-a-jquery-tab-programatically/17906109?noredirect=1#comment26308448_17906109)

you initialize the tabs, and afterwards, you select the wanted tab.

```
$(function() { 
  $( "#TabIdentifierIdInYourHTML" ).tabs(); 
  $( "#TabIdentifierIdInYourHTML" ).tabs( "option", "active", 2 ); 
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Try This:

```
$('#tabs').tabs({
    select: function(event, ui) { // select event
        $(ui.tab); // the tab selected
        ui.index; // zero-based index
    },
    show: function(event, ui) { // show event
        $(ui.tab); // the tab shown
        ui.index; // zero-based index
    }
});
```

[Found from  Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8020884/jquery-ui-tabs-get-current-tab-index)

Answer (score 0):

you can simply do this

```
$("#id").tabs( "select" , 1);
```

Comment: this is supposed to be deprecated